# How to Pass Data Table to SSRS Report Viewer?

Tags: sql, asp.net, reporting-services, datatable, ssrs-2008

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable ds = new DataTable();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();

    cmd.CommandText = StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@iDomainID", 1));

    foreach (var item in reportParams)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + item.ParameterName, "'" + item.FieldValue + "'"));
    }

    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(ds);

    conn.Close();

    string strFile;
    strFile = "Reports/" + ReportName;

    ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + strFile);
    string strReportdef = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + strFile;

    int iTables = 0;
    System.Collections.Generic.IList<string> ilReportDSs =   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetDataSourceNames();

    for (iTables = 0; iTables < ds.Columns.Count; iTables++)
    {
        ReportDataSource rdSource = new ReportDataSource(ilReportDSs[iTables], ds.Columns[iTables]);
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdSource);
    }

    ReportViewer1.DataBind();
}
```

This causes an error in

```
for (iTables = 0; iTables < ds.Columns.Count; iTables++)
{
    ReportDataSource rdSource = new ReportDataSource(ilReportDSs[iTables], ds.Columns[iTables]);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdSource);
}
```

For `ReportDataSource rdSource = new ReportDataSource(ilReportDSs[iTables], ds.Columns[iTables]);`

How should I pass data table to report viewer? Tried to change it to data set but this throws error for excecution of stored procedure using data set how will I pass using data table..?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
              this.CAreports.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(strDSN, ReportData));
```

Where strDSN is the name of a data set in the Report and ReportData is a data table containing the report data. So for each data set in the report you need to add a matching pair report Data Set Name and a data table containing the data for that data set. The Data Set Name must match to one in the report definition. The Columns in the Data table must match those in the Report data set.

For local reports you must provide the data to be displayed in the report. This is the key difference between a local report(.RDLC) and a server side report(.RDL). In fact you can write all your reports as server side reports using visual studio and simply run them as local reports by providing the data for them. The other key difference is server side reports allow you to use dynamic parameters whereas these have to be static for local reports, but again you simply provide the parameter values for them at run time.